# Codeigniter database session GET LOCK

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I have two webservers running Codeigniter framework and use a load balancer, and I want to store the shared session for both webservers instead of using sticky session from load balancer.

I tried to use ci database session. For few days the connections were excellent, until suddenly it start showing slow query like this:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('59e30181bfafeae2d31394d621bab3cc4c401956', 300) AS ci_session_lock;
```

The query can take from 5 - 15 seconds which slow down the servers.

This is the session configuration in config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0; //expire when the browser is closed 
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Does anyone ever experience like this? Thanks before.

Comment: move session to files instead of database.

Comment: Or use a separate memcached or Redis server to store the sessions. Then you can access it from all servers behind the load balancer and should be much faster than DB requests.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, thanks. I try this right away..

Comment: I have tried the Redis or memcached, but the session return errors sometimes. unable to read the session on save.path. Why so, is there any work around on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing slow query issue then you need to save your session into files instead of database, this will save your slow and multiple query request.

**Example:**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; // need to use files
```

**The storage driver to use in CI:** files, database, redis, memcached

Then define tmp path:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

According to PHP manual, [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) Returns directory path used for temporary files

You can also set specific folder to save session in `$config['sess_save_path']` as:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'session_folder'; // this will save session on root inside **session_folder** folder.
```

Comment: using different IPs for both? @yodann, if this is the case, then u can use third option `memcached`

Comment: where to install the memcached, is it one of the webservers or on another server?

Comment: i think from where you execute this CI project @yodann

Comment: if I use files instead, is it possible to store the file in a mounted location, so the path can be accessed by both webservers?

Comment: how about the owner of the files. as I see, the session files generated own by the php user, and still causes the application to request a relogin again. Can we change the owner to nobody so everyone can write on the files?

Comment: Will create session separately for each user @yodann

Comment: I have tried storing files on NFS, but the performance slower at the heavy load time. Any work around on NFS config?

Comment: from where you create files folder? @yodann

Comment: the NFS is on another server, as centralized, and all webservers read and store session to the mounted folder.